# Time-based events in MediaElements.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to trigger a callback when the player reaches a certain point on the time line.

My original thought was, using the player.currentTime call, to create a array of stop points.  This produces something like this:

`[1.8429549932479858, 2.831857919692993, 3.981297016143799]`

Next, using the `timeupdate` event listener, I attempted to compare the currentTime against my array to find a matching value.  I added some fuzzy matching, using Math.round, but couldn't get any consistent results.  The biggest issue I'm seeing is the `timeupdate` method only fires every 250ms.  For my application, that's not enough resolution.

My question is, is there a more direct method for doing this?

Your help is greatly appreciated!